# ZabbixAPI, retrieving information from a particular field within each host

Tags: zabbix

I want to retrieve the percentage of disk space left for a particular diskX: from all hosts within a particular host group.
I tried to work with the item.get() function but that returned an empty list.

> zapi =ZabbixApi(server)

```
for t in zapi.item.get(groups = 'Type1',filter = {'name': 'Free Disk Space on X'},)
```

This^^ method using the item.get method.
Gives me an empty list

I tried using the history.get method but that kept timing out

```
for t in groups:
  t2 += zapi.history.get(filter = {'name':'free Disk Space on E:(percentage)'},)
```

Anyone have any experience with Zabbix Api's to advice me on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited after more details regarding the request, see the comments.

To avoid php timeouts you should split your requests and use time_from/time_till as Jan suggested.

When using discovered items the item name obtained through the APIs will not expand the macros, there's a feature request about it.

For example if you use a Windows Filesystem Discovery and your server has C: and D: drives, in Zabbix you will have two items with the same name (`"Free disk space on $1 (percentage)"`), while the discovered drive will be in the `key_` field of each item, for instance:

```
vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]
vfs.fs.size[D:,pfree]
```

So, you will have to call the item get API filtering for the generic name (the `$1`), then get the history values only if the `key_` contains your target drive name

I've updated the sample script with a hostgroup filter and more verbose variables and output: edit out any non-needed field to simplify the output you need.

```
from zabbix.api import ZabbixAPI
import re
import time
import datetime

zapi = ZabbixAPI(url=zabbixServer, user=zabbixUser, password=zabbixPass)

# Static filters, implement argparse if needed
itemFilter = {  "name" : "Free disk space on $1 (percentage)"  }
hostgroupFilter = { "name": "Some HostGroup" }
keyFilter = "C\:"

# args.f and args.t supplied from cmd line - see argparse
fromTimestamp = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(args.f, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").timetuple())
tillTimestamp = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(args.t, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").timetuple())


# Get only the host of the specified hostgroup
hostGroup = zapi.hostgroup.get(filter=hostgroupFilter,output='extend')
hosts =  zapi.host.get(groupids=hostGroup[0]['groupid'],output='extend')

for host in hosts:
    items = zapi.item.get(filter=itemFilter, host=host['host'], output='extend' )

    for item in items:
        # Check if the item key contains the target object (in your example, if in contains C:)
        if re.search(keyFilter, item['key_']):

            values = zapi.history.get(itemids=item['itemid'], time_from=fromTimestamp, time_till=tillTimestamp, history=item['value_type'])
            for historyValue in values:
                currentDate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(historyValue['clock'])).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
                print "{}:{}({}) - {} {} Value: {}".format(
                  host['host'],
                  item['name'],
                  item['key_'],
                  historyValue['clock'],
                  currentDate, historyValue['value'])
```

Sample output of 5 minutes, hostgroup with 3 windows server

```
SRV01:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128853 28/09/2018 12:00:53 Value: 63.3960
SRV01:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128914 28/09/2018 12:01:54 Value: 63.3960
SRV01:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128974 28/09/2018 12:02:54 Value: 63.3960
SRV01:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538129034 28/09/2018 12:03:54 Value: 63.3960
SRV01:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538129094 28/09/2018 12:04:54 Value: 63.3960
SRV02:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128824 28/09/2018 12:00:24 Value: 52.2341
SRV02:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128885 28/09/2018 12:01:25 Value: 52.2341
SRV02:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128944 28/09/2018 12:02:24 Value: 52.2341
SRV02:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538129004 28/09/2018 12:03:24 Value: 52.2341
SRV02:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538129065 28/09/2018 12:04:25 Value: 52.2341
SRV03:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128828 28/09/2018 12:00:28 Value: 33.2409
SRV03:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128888 28/09/2018 12:01:28 Value: 33.2409
SRV03:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538128947 28/09/2018 12:02:27 Value: 33.2409
SRV03:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538129008 28/09/2018 12:03:28 Value: 33.2409
SRV03:Free disk space on $1 (percentage)(vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree]) - 1538129069 28/09/2018 12:04:29 Value: 33.2409
```

Comment: But the output doesn't give the percentage values, it gives me the names of all teh hosts within a particular hostgroup. I'm still playing around with it to figure it out completely. to pull the disk usage of C: as you mentioned, is the correct parameter referencing 'C: Disk Usage' ? or should I mention, 'Free space disk drive C:'?

Comment: The item filter in my code (`f  = {  'name' : 'C: Disk usage'  }`) is just a sample, replace the string with the exact item name you want to extract from all the hosts.

Comment: Thanks, for the help, I have a question regarding the information being printed. Since this is the history of the item can we add a filter on the history ? to narrow the search down even more?. As of this moment i'm getting all the values under a specific host, but there is no name beside the item id hence not giving me an idea about what value I am receiving.

Comment: well you could remove the print in the hosts iteration and replace the print in the historyValue iteration with `print "{} - {} {} Value: {}".format(host['host'], historyValue['clock'], currentDate, historyValue['value'])`

Comment: I did that, but it gives me all the history and does not narrow it down into free disk space C: hosts  and its values.

Comment: Everytime i use the filter while trying to get the items it returns an empty value, but when i manually go onto the zabbix latest data section under monitoring and put the filter name = Free disk space C: it returns a correct value under the particular hostgroup, and host. But why wont teh filter activate if we give it a host group and the filter name? shouldn't it narrow down all results with the name 'Free disk space.."

Comment: Your disk items are static or created by discovery? If the latter, there's one more step todo because the current API does not expand the drive name and there's another step to do

Comment: Just an addendum: you can ask the Zabbix api to filter for your `key_`, but you have to use the `search` request. Define the param like `keyFilter = { "key_" : "[C:,pfree]" }` and call the api with it: `items = zapi.item.get(filter=itemFilter, search=keyFilter, host=host['host'], output='extend' )`

Comment: Thanks, for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get full history (without time limitation) with `history.get()` - that can be a lot of datapoints, which needs to be preprocessed by API. That is a really not a good idea because you can reach some PHP/API limits - time or memory - that's your current case.

Use `time_from/time_till` parameters to limit time range of `history.get()`.
See doc: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/history/get

Comment: So, is this what I'm supposed to do then?                                                              `time_till=time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())                                                 
time_from=time_till-60*60*0.00277 #aka 1sec                                                                                                                               
for t in groups:
  t2 += zapi.history.get(time_from = time_from,time_till=time_till,filter = { 
  'name':'free Disk Space on E:(percentage)'},)`                 This method gives me a timeout message every time i use it

Comment: Try to use http://monitoringartist.github.io/zapix/ to find the correct parameter values. I guess you need to pass itemids parameter. I'm not sure if you can filter by name here. API doc + pyzabbix examples are a good start point.